# How to I deal with spaces in the output of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

Firstly, here's the code:

```
    alphabet = input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order: ")
    message = input("Now input the scrambled message: ")
    secret_map = {}
    for index, letter in enumerate(alphabet):
        secret_map[letter] = chr(65 + index)
    new_str = ("".join([secret_map[char] for char in message]))
    print(new_str, end="")

OUTPUT
Please input the scambled alphabet in order = DRLOWNUKSBZQJHCTXMIFYGPAEV
Now input the scrambled message = LOWNUK
CDEFGH
```

BUT

```
Please input the scambled alphabet in order = DRLOWNUKSBZQJHCTXMIFYGPAEV
Now input the scrambled message = LOWNUK LOWNUK
OUTPUT = 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/sanjith/Documents/assign8t.py", line 6, in <module>
        new_str = ("".join([secret_map[char] for char in message]))
      File "/Users/sanjith/Documents/assign8t.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
        new_str = ("".join([secret_map[char] for char in message]))
    KeyError: ' '
```

I'm having trouble getting spaces. I know it has something to do with ascii number 32(changed from 127 previously) for space.

Comment: What if you were to add an entry to `secret_map` for the space character, mapping space to itself?

Comment: Space is 32, not 127. The number has nothing to do with your problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
secret_map.get(char, char)
```